# How would you design & implement a Cross Platform synchronization mechanism?

Tags: synchronization, cross-platform

How would you design, architect and implement a Cross Platform synchronization mechanism ?

Targeted Platforms : Windows, Windows Mobile 6.5 & 7, Iphone, MacOs X, Android

It's for synchronizing a very simple desktop CRUD app.

Please note that I've got nothing running in a cloud, that's why I'm wondering if I can't capitalize on an existing reliable open (via an API) technology such as dropabox ?

Answer (score 0):

See [Synchronizing client-server databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406891/synchronizing-client-server-databases/3424880#3424880) for some issues with synchronization "in general".